WordPress api call from react Express server hosted on render.com timeout issue
I have a SaaS software that sends an API call over HTTP to my WordPress site on my react Express server. When the server is hosted locally, I recieve a response from my API call successfully. When I upload the server to Render.com, I reieve this error:
AxiosError: connect ETIMEDOUT 67.227.157.67:443
error: [Function: handleRequestError],
cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 67.227.157.67:443
Here is my API call:
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');

const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: true
});

const response = await axios.get(`${WpUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/categories`, {
  withCredentials: true,
  httpsAgent: agent,
});


Here is my server.js:
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.use(cors());

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  runInitiateRunTopic();
});


I am not entirely sure why I recieve these errors. The IP's my server is hosted on is not blacklisted anywhere. Any advice helps!
Thank you!
I have followed renders instructions on how to set the port ( const port = process.env.PORT || 1337; & port env var is set automatically ). I have also tried sending the API request with auth and headers.

Use await axios.get(.. within a async function.

The api call is within an async function. My backend of WordPress is showing me ModSecurity: Warning: msg "COMODO WAF: Inbound Points Exceeded.

Is it the only route path in the server ? Do you have the root route path or a test route path ? If so can you please see if it is accessible from outside -  from any Browser ? We are here trying to isolate the Express server and test it to see it is basically accessible from outside. And then try to access this test route from the the frontend app as well. This way we can pinpoint the point of failure if it is with the Wordpress site.

Turns out the WordPress site has blocked my hosting providers IP address for my server. I am searching for a work-around so I do not have to whitelist my hosting providers site on every new WordPress domain I use.

Noted. Thank you for your update and sharing this info. May you be able to find a solution for the present issue. All the bests.
